# Can I load a "config" file within a config file in CodeIgniter?

Tags: codeigniter

I have an "environment" config file that I'm using to separate dev from staging from prod and I'd like to include it in another config file to determine the proper path.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm assuming you want to load it from your `config.php` and/or `database.php`. Just include it like you'd include any other file in PHP (using either `include` or `require`).

```
require('environment_config.php');
```